# How can 400V & 690V on e-motors result in the same power

Tags: motor, three-phase, electrical

Forgive my ignorance, but how can two 3-phase ratings on the same motor result in the same output power?

The one I have is rated for 0.7kW in triangle for both 400V and 690V.

Comment: delta/star or triangle/star configuration. You can't connect this motor in triangle on 690V, but star. On 400V you connect it in triangle, power is the same.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I think it's the other way around; star/wye is 400V (phase-ground), and triangle/delta is 690V (phase-phase).

Comment: @marcelm: Marko is correct. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffKsdh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Connection possibilities.*

- On a 400 V phase-to-phase supply the motor windings are connected in delta (from the Greek 'D' or Δ).
- On a 690 V phase-to-phase supply the motor windings are connected in star or wye (from the American letter 'Y').
- From trigonometry you can show that the orange lines in Figure 1b are \$ \sqrt 3 \$ times the length of the black lines. \$ 400 \times \sqrt 3 = 692.8 \$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqyKHV.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Connection options.*

> How can two 3-phase ratings on the same motor result in the same output power?

In each case the voltage across each winding is 400 V so the same current will flow in each winding and the same power will be produced.

Comment: The 'American' letter? Well okay then transistor.

Comment: Ha! It's "star" on this side of the Atlantic. I've never seen "wye" as a *word* for 'Y' except in American literature.

Comment: Ah of course. I misread the name plate on the motor. Indeed it says 400/690 Δ/Y.
I confused it with being rated for both 50/60Hz.
Additional question: Since it is 400/690 for 50Hz and 480V/60Hz in Δ - what would the Y voltage @60Hz be? It isn't mentioned on the name plate.

Comment: 480*sqrt(3)~831V?

Comment: I've never seen 830 V mentioned anywhere. Maybe it can only be run in delta on a 60 Hz, 480 V supply. Don't forget that insulation breakdown voltage becomes a problem at some point.

Comment: "Y" in French is called "I grec" and means "Greek I" (an "I" like in the Greek alphabet). So Y in not an American letter.